# How is the accuracy as a metric in a Keras machine learning model calculated? Is it a valuable metric for LSTM

Tags: python, long-short-term-memory, keras, time-series, accuracy

I'm training a LSTM neural network for time series prediction in Keras. During the training of the model, the loss (mse) gradually decreases each epoch, but the accuracy as well as the validation accuracy stays rather low and doesn't really change.

The input set for the model is the energy consumption of a company for the last five days, recorded every 15 minutes. The output is the list of energy consumption during the next day, also recorded every 15 minutes. Is the accuracy a valuable metric to evaluate the model in this case, since I'm not trying to predict just one value?

I tried changing the model architecture, hyperparameters, etc. Nothing really changed, so I suppose the issue lies in the type of output format and the way the accuracy is being calculated.